# Changing the style of a linked element after the link has been visited?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change the style of a linked element after it has been visited. I tried accomplishing this using css and jquery with no success.

If I remove the ':visited' below it works as expected and all elements have the style noted below. However when I try to apply the style only to the visited element, no style is applied and I can't seem to figure out why:/

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rN9gA/1/

jquery

```
$("#numresults a:visited div").css("border","3px solid #777777");
```

HTML

```
<div id="numresults">               
    <a class="results-per-page" href="search.php?option=1"><div>6</div></a>
    <a class="results-per-page" href="search.php?option=2"><div>12</div></a>
    <a class="results-per-page" href="search.php?option=3"><div>24</div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using CSS instead of jQuery. Also, because of the potential for exploiting the `:visited` pseudo-class, some browsers don't allow JavaScript to access that information. Oh, and a block-level element (the `div`) within an in-line element (the `a`) is invalid in HTML other than HTML 5.

Comment: I tried using CSS alone and it did not work. No style is applied when I do that :(

Comment: The last link in your HTML code above has an error. `24>/div>` should be `24</div>`. If it's on the real site as well, make sure to fix it.

Comment: so there are no fixes for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use jQuery for this, just use CSS.

`#numresults a:visited div{border:3px solid #777777;}`

JavaScript can't check :visited links because of privacy concerns, however, there are workarounds.

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work. When I try to use css alone, no style is applied.

Comment: Very odd. I think it might be a browser restriction or bug. If you set colour, it works. If you set border or width (etc) it doesn't.

Comment: A work-around I found is this: 
`#numresults a div{border:3px solid #FFFFFF;}` -> set border to have the same colour as your background so it's not visible. It will enlarge your links 3px on all sides though.
`#numresults a:visited div{border:3px solid #777777;}` -> colours the border differently.